# I'm trying to create a bootable usb for ubuntu 20.04 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: usb

I'm busy following this tutorial: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview

The installation was working until it asked for permission to install the bootloader

Should I let it install this?
My plan is to use this 20.04 USB on a Windows 10 PC without changing windows itself

Thank You for any help

Comment: Which point version 'x' of **12.04.x LTS** are you running? 12.04.5 is the newest and 'best' because it has the kernel of 14.04 LTS. Is it 32-bit or 64 bit? Is it Ubuntu Desktop or Ubuntu Server? Your answers to these questions make a difference (unless you are prepared to clone from the iso file to the USB drive with the risky tool `dd` without a final checkpoint alias 'safety belt'). When I get your answers, I can test and find a method that works.

Comment: **Gnome-Disks** should be able to extract the 20.04 ISO file to USB. This will make a clone the same as dd or etcher make. If the OP's computer boots UEFI then all that is needed is to extract the 20.04 ISO to a FAT32 or NTFS partition on the USB, using **Archive Manager** etc.

Comment: Oops, back in the days of 12.04 Gnome-Disk-Utility did not seem to have the ability to clone ISO files to USB drives. Sorry. Archive Manager works for extracting 20.04 though.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 has passed its End-of-life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu.

Comment: @waltinator, The OP is trying to upgrade to 20.04 from 12.04, according to Ask Help this is on-topic.

Comment: @sudodus a few months ago I was able to install the current mkusb to Ubuntu 14.04 ESM and it worked fine. I have just tried mkusb with 12.04 and end up with problems such as lots of broken packages. One problem is I can only get 32bit version working, I think my 64bit version is broken.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron, Yes I know. Many things have changed, and mkusb has been modified to work with current versions of Ubuntu, and 12.04 LTS is behind that window now. **I am waiting for answers from the OP, Penny Hughes, to my questions (in the first comment)**. With those answers I should be able to test what works (I'm thinking of tools that are safer than `dd`) and recommend that to the OP.

Answer (score 2):

### Create a Bootable USB for Ubuntu 20.04 using Ubuntu 12.04

There **are not** many options for creating a 20.04 bootable USB using 12.04 besides for dd.

Startup Disk Creator, Unetbootin, Etcher, Gnome-Disks, Ventoy and mkusb* do not work.

**Method that works for UEFI boot computers.**

- Format the USB drive as either FAT32 or NTFS, FAT32 preferred especially if persistence is in the future..
- In 12.04 Disk Utility, right click your 20.04 ISO file and select `Open with Archive Manager`.
- Click `Extract` and select your USB drive.

Once extraction is complete the USB will boot to Ubuntu 20.04 on a UEFI computer.

**Method that works for BIOS boot computers.**

- Extract the ISO file to USB as above.
- Install grub, if in BIOS mode or booted from USB drive run:

  ```
    sudo mount /dev/sdx1 /mnt

    sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdx
  ```

where sdx is your USB drive.

The USB will now boot to Ubuntu 20.04 on a BIOS/Legacy mode computer and a UEFI computer.

(This is almost easier than using Etcher).

*dd via mkusb-min worked okay, see sudodus answer.

Comment: Our OP seems to have abandoned us. But similar questions will be asked again, so a good answer is valuable. I think your answer is perfect for UEFI mode. But I was not sure for BIOS mode. I did some testing, and yes, your instructions work for BIOS mode too :-) I had some problem to get the Archive Manager to work correctly, but found out how to do it. Command line is much easier for me. - Comment: I think many but far from all computers boot in UEFI mode from NTFS.

Answer (score 1):

### `mkusb-min` wraps a safety belt around `dd`.

I will suggest a command-line method with a simple shell-script `mkusb-min`. It is simple, the shellscript is very small compared to the other versions of mkusb, yet it serves the purpose to wrap a safety belt around `dd`.

`mkusb-min` works in old versions of Ubuntu as well as from most other Linux distros. It needs `bash, dd, grep, ls, lsblk, sed, sleep, sort, tr, /dev/disk/by-id`, some standard tools and features, that were present in almost all current linux distros 2017, and also in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

You find instructions when you search the internet with the search string **mkusb-min** or something similar, or directly with

[mkusb minimal shellscript - mkusb-min](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/min)

There are detailed instructions at that website how to download, check and use `mkusb-min`.

First you should make it executable

```
cd Downloads/
sudo chmod +x mkusb-min
```

You get a short help text when you run the command without any parameters.

```
sudo ./mkusb-min
```

or with full path for example

```
$ sudo /home/penny/Downloads/mkusb-min
 Run 'mkusb-min' with sudo or as root 
               This shellsript wraps a safety belt around 'dd'               
Clone from an iso or image file to a target device (typically a USB pendrive)
Usage:
 sudo /path/mkusb-min <source file> <target device> 
Examples:
 sudo /home/penny/Downloads/mkusb-min file.iso /dev/sdx
 sudo /home/penny/Downloads/mkusb-min file.img /dev/sdx
Help:
/home/penny/Downloads/mkusb-min -h
Version:
/home/penny/Downloads/mkusb-min -v
Available devices (tran-MODEL  device),
 nvme-eui.0026b7282486d045  /dev/nvme0n1 
 nvme-KINGSTON_SA2000M8250G_50026B7282486D04  /dev/nvme0n1 
 ata-SanDisk_SD6SB1M256G1001_143104401008  /dev/sda 
 ata-WDC_WD4002FYYZ-01B7CB1_K3GWHAEB  /dev/sdb 
 usb-SanDisk_Cruzer_Blade_00008126121320014148-0:0  /dev/sdc 
 ata-PLDS_DVD-RW_DH16AESH_S0C19802ZVJ8EZ00N797  /dev/sr0
```

In this example the Sandisk USB pendrive at `/dev/sdc` is a suitable target device.

Comment: **mkusb-min** worked for me on 12.04 and I was able to clone the 20.04 ISO file okay. (but I am still not a big fan of Command Line), Thanks +1