# Is making a bootable hard disk without unetbooting possible?

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, hard-drive, bootloader

I'm asking this because unetbootin not working.

(i dont have a usb disc)

Comment: Yes; you can write an ISO to a disk, boot it and install to a different disk, or you can write the ISO to a partition on the existing disk and have your boot loader offer to boot and run it, and install to a different drive or same drive but different partition (some boot loaders are easy to do this with, others (like microsoft windows) are a pain & using thumb-drive is far easier).  You can also use any media your hardware will boot from (flash memory cards etc).

Comment: In Windows, alternatives to UNetbootin include Rufus, Etcher, YUMI, Ventoy and Universal USB Installer. In Linux alternatives to UNetbootin include dd, Gnome-Disks, Etcher, Ventoy, Startup Disk Creator (from ISO) and mkusb. If the Computer boots UEFI you can just extract the ISO to USB or to a small partition on the hard drive and UEFI will boot it. **To Boot Ubuntu Live without USB** see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1357386/43926

Comment: @karel: I do not see that the OP has GRUB installed on his computer. Both of the Duplicated Questions depend on GRUB to boot the Live installer ISO. Your links do not help the OP as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.But as i said i don't have a usb flash disk and im using normal bios.

Comment: You should be able to use the 'grub and iso' method described in the accepted answer of the second link in the 'duplicate statement' : [Install Ubuntu from ISO image directly from hard disk of a system running Linux? [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/340156/install-ubuntu-from-iso-image-directly-from-hard-disk-of-a-system-running-linux). That method works both in the newer UEFI mode and the older BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode), but you need an existing grub boot system for it to work.

Comment: @tokmaq, It is not clear what you mean by 'normal bios'. Both UEFI mode and BIOS mode are normal. -- If you have not an existing grub boot system, and boot in UEFI mode, the method suggested by C.S.Cameron works. Otherwise, if you boot in BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode), I strongly suggest that you get (borrow or buy) a USB pendrive and create USB boot drive in order to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you running Windows in the computer? In that case which version? Is it factory-installed? Are you running Ubuntu or some other Linux distro? In that case which version? What computer is it (Brand name and model)? -- The answers can help us give you more relevant answers, we can focus on *your* particular case.

Comment: In my first comment I described what I've done on boxes that didn't have working *bootable* USB drives (booted from partition, or file on partition) which allowed running a *live* system (inc. install) booted from boot manager already existing on your machine (inc. only windows but was easier with other OSes & booting partition was easier than ISO file on *fs*. I had to use it as USB ports had failed, replacement ones the firmware/BIOS would not allow boot from. My comment (not answer) was for non-flash-disk & BIOS box

Comment: Do you have an Android phone? DriveDroid will turn your phone into a USB drive: https://askubuntu.com/questions/925400/how-to-install-ubuntu-using-a-smart-phone-as-the-installation-media